# How to find biggest of three numbers using command line arguments in shell script?

Tags: unix

Please help me in executing this.I am new learning unix!
Write a shell script to find out biggest of three numbers. Assume that inputs are given as command line argument, and if this three numbers are not given show error message as “command line arguments are missing”.

Sample Input 1:

10 20 30

Sample Output1:

30 is Biggest number

Sample Input 1:

10 10 10

Sample Output1:

All the three numbers are equal

Sample Input 1:

10 10 1

Sample Output1:

I cannot figure out which number is biggest

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service where we do your homework for you. Try reading some tutorials and attempt a solution - then if you are still having problems you can post a [MCVE] of your issue including what you have tried and the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
read a b c
if [[ $a == 0 || $b == 0 || $c == 0 ]]; then
    echo "command line arguments are missing"
elif [[ $a == $b && $b == $c ]]; then
    echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [[  $a == $b && $b > $c  ||  $b == $c && $c > $a ||  $a == $c && $a > $b  ]]; then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is biggest"
else
    if [[ $a > $b && $a > $c ]]; then 
        echo "$a is Biggest number"
    elif [[ $b > $a && $b > $c ]]; then
        echo "$b is Biggest number"
    else
        echo "$c is Biggest number"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk. Works for exactly 3 values but easy to generalize:

```
$ echo 20 20 20 | awk -v RS="[ \n]" '
{ a[$0] }                  # hash all values to a
END {
    for(i in a) {          # loop all values in hash
        if(m==""||i>m)     # decide bigger
            m=i
        j++ }              # count values in hash
    switch(j) {
    case "1": 
        print "All equal"  # not sure if these make any sense:
        break
    case "2": 
        print "No figure"  # if repeating values, there is still biggest value
        break
    case "3": 
        print m " biggest"
        break
    }
}'
All equal
```

Answer (score 0):

`if [ $# -ne 3 ] 
then 
  echo "command line arguments are missing"
  exit 1
fi
  if [ $1 -eq $2 -a $1 -eq $3 ]
      then
      echo "All the three numbers are equal"
  elif [[  $1 -eq $2 && $1 -ge $3  ||  $2 -eq $3 && $2 -ge $1  ||   $3 -eq $1 && $1 -ge $2  ]]
      then
      echo "I cannot figure out which number is biggest"
  elif [ $1 -gt $2 -a $1 -gt $3  ]
      then
      echo "$1 is Biggest number"
  elif [ $2 -gt $3 -a $2 -gt $1 ]
      then 
      echo "$2 is Biggest number"
  else
      echo "$3 is Biggest number"
fi`

Answer (score -1):

### **Here have a look at it:**

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then 
    echo "command line arguments are missing"
elif [ $1 -eq $2 ]&&[ $2 -eq $3 ]
then
    echo "All the three are equal"
elif [ $1 -eq $2 ]||[ $1 -eq $3 ]
then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is biggest"
elif [ $1 -gt $2 ]
then
    if [ $1 -gt $3 ]
    then
        echo "$1 is biggest number"
    else
        echo "$3 is biggest number"
    fi
elif [ $2 -gt $3 ]
then
    echo "$2 is biggest number"
else
    echo "$3 is biggest number"
fi
```